# Seeking comparison site for SBCs (and would it be on-topic to ask on our main site?)

Tags: discussion, site-scope

After my (unanswered) question [Seeking ESP32 with display which is supported by the PlatformIO debugger](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/4318/seeking-esp32-with-display-which-is-supported-by-the-platformio-debugger), I thought that I would scrape the PlatformIO docs at https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/boards/index.html

That, at least, would let me scraped the linked pages of individual boards fro the phrase "`PIO Unified Debugger - “1-click” solution for debugging with a zero configuration`" and produce a list of those boards which native support debugging, without the need for a JTAG probe.

Then I thought to generate an AngularJs web page with dentils, and a grid sortable on processor speed, RAM & Flash size.

Alas, the PlatformIo docs don't say which boards have a display, and I would also like to know which have a Grove connector.

Suddenly, this is looking like quite a project, and I wonder if I am reinventing the wheel.

Does anyone know of a website with details of SBCs, which is searchable & sortable and kept up to date?

And would it be on-topic to ask this on our main site?